# Lettuce and strange characters

Tags: python, lettuce

I tried to run Lettuce. Normally works, however when I used:

```
lettuce | less
```

there are a lot of color commands like:

```
ESC[1;37m
```

How to get rid of that when writing into file?

For example cucumber prints nice colors in the console, and normal text in less and file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ lettuce | less -R   # keep the colors
```

or

```
$ lettuce -v 3        # remove the colors
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable [`DISABLE_COLORS`](http://packages.python.org/pycolors/):

`export DISABLE_COLORS=true`

Any value should work, I just picked `true` for semantics.